# get rid of the decimal comma and parentheses in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

if I print "videosvar" It prints the number like this:[18.]
How do I get rid of the decimal comma and parentheses

```
videos = round(pd.read_excel(r'C:\pydata.xlsx', sheet_name=0, header=0, names=None, index_col=None, usecols="C"))
videosvar = (videos.loc[num].values)
print(videosvar)
```

Comment: please edit you question to provide the output of `videos.head().to_dict()`

Comment: Use `videos.loc[num].values[0]` or `videos['C'].loc[num]`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np
videosvar = videosvar.astype(np.int64)
```

It should help if you need to make all dataframe columns integer.

P.S. Getting rid of parentheses (when videosvar is already a numpy array got by .values()):

```
print(*videosvar)
```

Comment: It only removes the decimal point and does not remove the parentheses

Comment: I've editted the comment